# Freeze axisLeft in MPAdnroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Is it possible to set axisLeft to be always present on screen, while horizontal scrolling the chart? I would like to see the Y values all the time

Comment: In general it should always stay fixed when scrolling by default. Are you seeing that to not be the case? If so, please update your question to include an example that shows that behavior.